# jquery each function for menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

hello guys i have a menu. i want to add a toogle animation to each parent menu.
but curently i stuck, because when i click the parent menu. all parent menu show their child menu.
i think i need a jquery each function, but i dont know how to implement with my case.
heres my code

```
$(".menu-item-has-children").prepend("<i></i>");
$(".menu-item-has-children").find("i").addClass("fa fa-plus-circle toogle-icon");
$(".toogle-icon").click(function(){
  $(".sub-menu").slideToggle();
});
```

heres jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/Lypj8tov/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".toogle-icon").click(function(){
  $(this).parent('.menu-item-has-children').find(".sub-menu").slideToggle();
});
```

Also you may simplify the whole thing:

```
$('<i class="fa fa-plus-circle toogle-icon"></i>')
  .click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".sub-menu").slideToggle();
  })
  .prependTo(".menu-item-has-children");
```

Check https://fiddle.jshell.net/ermakovnikolay/q5z4b64u/

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer the relative element to the clicked instance. Using `this`:

```
$(".toogle-icon").click(function(){
  $(this).siblings('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
});
```

## [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lypj8tov/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".toogle-icon").click(function(){
  $(this).closest('.menu-item-has-children').find(".sub-menu").slideToggle();
});
```

@Nikolay Ermakov thanks man, why u delete ur answer? is it have a bug?

Comment: waw. more effective. dude u have any suggestion for make it work when resize. i mean on real time. so when i shrinking the window it take effect asap. on my code i need to refresh the jsfiddle to fire the jquery https://jsfiddle.net/Lypj8tov/3/

Comment: You would wrap your code in `$(window).on('resize', function() { ...your code here... });`

Comment: hmmm where i put the spesific resolution like fire that function when < 768 for example

Comment: Like so:  `$(window).on('resize', function() { if (window.innerWidth <768) {...your code here...}    });`

Comment: dude sorry, but it looping forever every time i minimalize the window. and when i resize the screen to make it bigger the icon still in there (its supposed to be gone)

Comment: For the icon to disappear I guess you would need to check the bigger screen size too like `if (window.innerWidth >=768) {...hide icon...}`. Not sure about the looping though. The best way would be to add the code you have in mind to a fiddle and drop here a link.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
$(".toogle-icon").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().find(".sub-menu").slideToggle();
});
```